# SQL Query is giving wrong Sums when trying to calculate repeated items in ( Recieved Table & Recieved Table )

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have 4 Tables
Books ( id , BkName )
Clients (id , C_name )
Received ( id , Book , Amount )
Delivered ( id , Book , Client , Amount )
I can receive the same book many times , and deliver it many times to the same client or to more than one client .
when I tried to figure out what books and how many of them is received and not delivered yet , I did this :

```
SELECT Books.BkName,
       Sum(Recieved.Amount) AS [Recieved Sum],
       Sum(Delivered.Amount) AS [Delivered Sum]
FROM   (Books LEFT JOIN Recieved ON Books.id = Recieved.Book)
       LEFT JOIN Delivered ON Books.id = Delivered.Book
GROUP BY Books.BkName;
```

I got wrong Sums ( more than the amount of books I received or delivered ) and I couldn't find a way to subtract ( Received - Delivered ) to get the result .
Thank you in advance for your time ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of query is probably best done using correlated subqueries:

```
select Books.*,
       (select Sum(Received.Amount) from Received where Books.id = Received.Book) as ReceivedTotal,
       (select Sum(Delivered.Amount) from Delivered where Books.id = Delivered.Book) as DeliveredTotal
from Books;
```

The problem with your version is that it creates a Cartesian product of received and delivered records for each book.  Hence, the sums end up being way off.

Note:  In English, the word is "receive" not "recieve".  There is an old mnemonic trick, "'i' before 'e' except after 'c' or when sounding like an "a" as in the 'neighbor' and 'weigh'".  Of course, this being English, there are zillions of exceptions even to the rule.

Comment: Thank you Very much for your help , it was great help for me .. I know the old mnemonic trick you mentioned but it didn't occur to my mind this time .. would you please recommend an SQL book that can help me to improve my knowledge about that ..